# Do not use svcutil or visual studio 2010 to generate a config file. why?

Tags: wcf

In the IDesign WCF Coding Standard, one of the points Juval Lowy makes is to not use svcutil or visual studio 2010 to generate the config file.  Can someone explain the advantage/disadvantage of this?

Comment: Does he explain his reasons for thinking this? Otherwise I would just ignore it, I would still ignore it, unless it came from Microsoft.  I am talking about the coding standard not being from Microsoft.

Comment: No, the majority of the pdf just lists some points.  I am not sure if he goes into more depth in his book (I do not have it).

Comment: Presumably he means to use the WCF Service Config Editor. Surely he doesn't mean maintaining it by hand ;)

Comment: I took a look at this document. It looks like it is useless. It does not provide a reason, thus there is no reason to believe it, like I said I wouldn't a coding standard unless it was generated by Microsoft and/or at least one that went into full detail.

Comment: One reason I brought it up is because I see Juval Lowy's name popup whenever WCF pops up, so I thought his opinion would have some merit.

Comment: Even if you aren’t going to follow them, recommendations from IDesign are always worth understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument is one of maintainability/readability of the config files. Lowy refers to a Visual Studio 2010 config file filled with default values as being butchered and unreadable. He recommends:

> open the file, add (or update) the reference, and then perform a
>   single Undo (Ctrl-Z) and manually add the config file entries in the
>   *client* section.
>
> Programming WCF Services 3rd Edition, by Juval Lowy p59

Comment: His information predates .NET 4.0, which does not emit all of those default values into the config file. It also includes default endpoints so, in many cases, endpoint information is not required at all in the config file.